# DLL naming under Windows

Tags: windows, dll, naming-conventions

How did Microsoft come up with those strange name for DLL?

Under System32:

- OUTLFLTR.DLL
- REFIEBAR.DLL

Under the Office dir:

- dfshim.dll
- KBDFA.DLL

Would have not been better a full name to understand better their role?
Is there a particular naming convenction they follow?
And, when you build Dlls do you usually follow a pattern to give them a name?

Comment: Looks like these names are trying to conform to 8.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like [commenter Ic. said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17803632/dll-naming-under-windows#comment25975956_17803632), these names conform to the old 8.3 naming convention: 8 characters for the file name, a period to indicate the start of the file extension, and a 3 character file extension. Such was the standard back in the DOS days, maintained through 16-bit Windows, and only gradually lifted as long file name support was introduced with 32-bit Windows.

But even with long file name support, [system files still tend to adhere to the old 8.3 naming convention](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/02/2008357.aspx). There are various reasons, which the linked article discusses in some detail. Backwards compatibility is a big one, as usual. And then there's the fact that most of the names were chosen many years ago, during the development of Windows NT, which had to run on FAT volumes that didn't necessarily support long file names. Like Raymond says, long file name support became ubiquitous in Windows XP and there you can find some system files that use file names longer than 8 characters, but they're still relatively rare.

And although some of your examples are from Microsoft Office, the Office team presumably follows the example (and advice) of the Windows teams. Not to mention the fact that they could have been named a very long time ago for one of the early versions of Office (we're on like version *15* now!), and the name can't be changed now for backwards compatibility reasons.

So yes, they probably would have given them a better name if circumstances have allowed. Current versions of Windows contain a fair number of files with longer names. Lots of third-party software uses DLLs with longer names. You probably won't have any trouble if you do the same. But sometimes, especially if you're writing critical operating system components, the guarantee of safety and acceptability takes precedence over vanity. Besides, what do you care if your file names are understandable to regular people? They're not supposed to be snooping around system files anyway.

Some of that applies to third-party app developers, too. You need to choose names that are meaningful to *you* and your team, but there's no reason that your users need to understand your naming conventions. The DLLs aren't for them, they're private support files for your app. At this point in time, for new development, I wouldn't worry about using long file names, but you still have to type them in, so there's no reason to go wild.

Note that, although this isn't a .NET question, things changed radically in the world of managed code. The length of file names virtually *exploded*, completely abandoning the old 8.3 format. You frequently see things like `Microsoft.VisualStudioAnalyzer.PrimaryEventCollector.dll`. Managed DLLs are identified and loaded using a completely different mechanism that is based on metadata instead of just the file name, so they don't have to worry about the problems that plague native DLLs. If you're a .NET developer, this is a perfectly valid model to follow.